# MySql Error 1005 errno 22

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help when i try to create this table

```
CREATE TABLE `sepetbol`.`ManRInMv|` (
  `CodResIns` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo resultado inspeccion',
  `FecResIns` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de resultado de Inspeccion',
  `ConActual` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contador Actual',
  `TieDuracion` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Tiempo Duracion de la Inspeccion',
  `ImaDoc` LONGBLOB COMMENT 'Imagen del Documento',
  `DesTipCod` VARCHAR(4) COMMENT 'Descripcion del Tipo de Doc',
  `CodMecanico` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Codigo Empleado Mecanico',
  `CodObra` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Codigo de Obra',
  `CodEquipo` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Codigo de Equipo',
  PRIMARY KEY(`CodResIns`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CodMecanicoRIn` FOREIGN KEY `FK_CodMecanicoRIn` (`CodMecanico`)
    REFERENCES `rhuempme` (`CodEmp`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CodObraRIn` FOREIGN KEY `FK_CodObraRIn` (`CodObra`)
    REFERENCES `genobrme` (`CodObra`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CodEquipoRIn` FOREIGN KEY `FK_CodEquipoRIn` (`CodEquipo`)
    REFERENCES `almequme` (`CodEqu`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT

COMMENT = 'Resultado de Inspeccion';
```

The constraints are well also not are not repeated incopatibilidad data type

I've been searching the net about this arror ... and there is nothing that my problem solutions

Comment: For foreign key constraints to work you must have compatible table types (InnoDB, not MyISAM), identical field types (all INT or VARCHAR or whatever - no mixed connections with INT referring to VARCHAR, for example), the target tables must exist before you create the constraint, the referred columns must be indexed,  and any existing data must pass the constraint(this doesn't apply for a new table). Check and check again. You've missed something.

Comment: have you tried to use the name without pipe "|" in in? This error is related to creating temporary tables and this name can break stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

1. close your create table syntax like:

   create table (field...);

Right now it is not closed with ending bracket.

1. Please check if all your master tables data type is "integer unsigned", just change if different in any master table and it will work.